# Correcting the sort order of pandas index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like the following. My `Date` field is of dtype `datetime64[ns]`:

```
           symbol        high         low
Date                                      
2018-08-16     spy  285.040009  283.359985
2018-08-17     spy  285.559998  283.369995
2018-08-16    nflx  331.170013  321.209991
2018-08-17    nflx  324.369995  312.959991
2017-07-17     spy  245.910004  245.330002
2017-07-18     spy  245.720001  244.669998
```

My goal is to set an index by `symbol` first and then by `Date` like the following:

```
                          high         low
symbol Date 
spy     2017-07-17  245.910004  245.330002
        2017-07-18  245.720001  244.669998                             
        2018-08-16  285.040009  283.359985
        2018-08-17  285.559998  283.369995
nflx    2018-08-16  331.170013  321.209991
        2018-08-17  324.369995  312.959991
```

Following is my attempt:
After resetting Date index by doing, the output looks like the following:

```
df.reset_index(level=['Date'], inplace=True)

        Date symbol        high         low
0 2018-08-16     spy  285.040009  283.359985
1 2018-08-17     spy  285.559998  283.369995
2 2018-08-16    nflx  331.170013  321.209991
3 2018-08-17    nflx  324.369995  312.959991
4 2017-07-17     spy  245.910004  245.330002
5 2017-07-18     spy  245.720001  244.669998
```

And finally setting the index on symbol and Date which is returning the undesired output:

```
df.set_index(['symbol', 'Date'], inplace=True)

                          high         low
symbol Date                              
spy     2018-08-16  285.040009  283.359985
        2018-08-17  285.559998  283.369995
nflx    2018-08-16  331.170013  321.209991
        2018-08-17  324.369995  312.959991
spy     2017-07-17  245.910004  245.330002
        2017-07-18  245.720001  244.669998
```

Comment: what's the order criteria? first by symbol then by date?

Comment: @Yuca. Yes, that's the order criteria.

Comment: then df.sort_index() is your friend :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, You can try using [`swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) followed by `sort_index`:

```
df.set_index('symbol', append=True).swaplevel().sort_index(level=[0,1],ascending=[False,True])

                         high         low
symbol Date                              
spy    2017-07-17  245.910004  245.330002
       2017-07-18  245.720001  244.669998
       2018-08-16  285.040009  283.359985
       2018-08-17  285.559998  283.369995
nflx   2018-08-16  331.170013  321.209991
       2018-08-17  324.369995  312.959991
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a fan of `inplace`, but try [pd.sort_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df.reset_index(level=['Date'], inplace= True)
df.set_index(['symbol', 'Date'], inplace=True)
print(df.sort_index())
```

Output:

```
                        high         low
symbol Date                              
nflx   2018-08-16  331.170013  321.209991
       2018-08-17  324.369995  312.959991
spy    2017-07-17  245.910004  245.330002
       2017-07-18  245.720001  244.669998
       2018-08-16  285.040009  283.359985
       2018-08-17  285.559998  283.369995
```